# Require custom post type if is_admin() - template doesn't show up?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, templates

In my functions.php I require PHP files which register custom post types, if I'm logged in as an admin.

```
if (is_admin())
    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/custom-post-types/cpt.php');
```

This works great, except that the wrong template is loaded. Instead of `single-{cpt}.php` the `index.php` is used. If I remove `if (is_admin())` everything works correct, but of course the custom post type becomes visible for every non-admin.

How can I solve that?

Comment: See @s_ha_dum's answer regarding your misunderstanding of the `is_admin()` conditional. But for answering the underlying question, I have one of my own: **what is the purpose of only registering CPTs when the current user is an Administrator?** What are you trying to accomplish with that? I think there may be a better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do, but we need to have a better idea of what the ultimate objective is.

Comment: I wanted to check my CPT template on the live machine and deny access to the template and CPT for non-admins.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't register the CPT then index.php will be used, and if you only register the CPT ***for the backend***, which is what [`is_admin`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) checks for, then `index.php` will pretty much always be used.

In other words, you are only registering your CPT for the backend, not for the front. It isn't ever going to work correctly that way.

What you are doing wrong is fundamentally misunderstanding the `is_admin` function.

I think what you need is `current_user_can` but you wouldn't want to register the post type on that switch, or I don't think you do. That will probably cause unwanted behavior as well, but of course you are welcome to try. Maybe something like...

```
function hide_cpt($content) {
  global $post; // might not be necessary
  if ('your-post-type-name' == $post->post_type && current_user_can('administrator')) {
   return 'You can\'t look at this';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','hide_cpt');
```

It is hard to say for sure if that will do what you want though. Your description isn't heavy on detail.

Comment: Sorry that I can't upvote you, but you are completely right. I misunderstood `is_admin`, because I thought it means _user is admin_ and not _user is in backend_.